# servidor web local error con pagina jsp

Tags: linux, apache, jsp, glassfish

He montado un servidor web publico en mi casa(Abrí el puerto 80 de mi router y lo dirigí a mi computador) simplemente para testear proyectos hasta ahí todo normal el problema es que yo estoy usando apache y este no soporta paginas JSP, lo que voy haciendo en JSP lo he estado probando con GlassFish pero este no me sirve para testearlo en una red fuera de la mía.

¿Que tendría que hacer? cambiar el puerto de GlassFish por el puerto 80 que es el que tengo abierto en mi router?

por cierto uso Debian por si hay alguna alternativa

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar Glassfish a quese ejecute en el puerto 80 necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

1. Conectarse a la interfaz de administración (por default en el puerto
       4848)
2. En el menú de la izquierda ir a "Configurations"
3. Después seleccionar la configuración apropiada, ej. "server-config"
4. Después ir a "Network Config"
5. Después ir a "Network Listeners"
6. Selecciona el "listener" correspondiente, probablemente "http-listener"
7. Cambia el valor "Port" a 80
8. Graba y reinicia el servidor Glassfish

Esto te debe permitir tener acceso al servidor en el puerto 80, sin que tengas que hacer cambios en tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Todos los routers tienen la opción de redirigir un puerto externo a uno interno, que no tiene porque ser el mismo. Es decir puedes configurar el puerto externo de tu IP publica en el 80, de tal manera que cuando alguien vaya a esa IP y puerto, vaya a tu IP privada (la de tu ordenador) al puerto donde este corriendo GlasFish, que normalmente es el 8080. Otra cosa es que tengas un IP fija,o un DNS dinámico.

Ejemplo: 
Tu IP publica es 1.1.1.1, pues rediriges el puerto 80, a tu IP privada, 192.168.1.1 pero al puerto 8080.

Como hacerlo depende del router, pero suele ser bastante facil.